# grep -v and -B|-A|-C not working together

Tags: perl, command-line, grep, solaris, iostat

I need to scan the output of `iostat -En` on a Solaris machine such that when a disk with errors is found, two lines about that disk are sent to the final output. This works fine so far using

```
iostat -En | grep 'Errors: [1-9]' -A 1
```

but when I try to not include CD/DVD devices, I hit a wall. The contaxt flags (`-A|B|C`) don't seem to work with `-v` so I can't use this:

```
-bash-4.0$ iostat -En | grep -B 1 -vi "CD/DVD" | grep 'Errors: [1-9]' -A 1
c0t3d0           Soft Errors: 2 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: TSSTcorp Product: CD/DVDW TS-L632D Revision: SR02 Serial No:
```

I don't think there should be any output here because the line containing "CD/DVD" and the line before it should be removed. It would be simple enough to write this as a script in any language but it has to be a single command that can be run on hosts without additional scripts installed so I suppose `perl -e` can be used. I don't know *any* perl so I haven't tried this approach.

Some example `iostat -En` output:

```
-bash-4.0$ iostat -En
c0t0d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: SEAGATE  Product: ST973402SSUN72G  Revision: 0603 Serial No: *removed*
Size: 73.40GB <73400057856 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t3d0           Soft Errors: 2 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: TSSTcorp Product: CD/DVDW TS-L632D Revision: SR02 Serial No:
Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 2 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t1d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: SEAGATE  Product: ST973402SSUN72G  Revision: 0603 Serial No: *removed*
Size: 73.40GB <73400057856 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
```

In this case, I should not have any output because the only device with errors is an optical drive and I don't care about those.

```
c0t1d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 1 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: SEAGATE  Product: ST973402SSUN72G  Revision: 0603 Serial No: *removed*
```

This is the output I am looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `nawk`

```
iostat -En | nawk '/Errors: [1-9]/{ getline line; if (line!~/CD|DVD/) print line}
```

Comment: Your solution worked with one small problem; it did not include the first line (c0t0d0 Soft Errors...) which was a small fix -- I just changed `print line}` to `{print; print line}}`

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v pattern` prints all lines that don't match a pattern, 
but `grep -B 1 -v pattern` also prints out all lines before lines that don't match a pattern, including lines that do match the pattern.

For example, if `file` contains:

```
ABCD
DEFG
GHIJ
```

Then `grep -v D file` gives you:

```
GHIJ
```

but `grep -B1 -v D file` gives you:

```
DEFG
GHIJ
```

The kind of processing you want is too complex for `grep`.